# GWT RemoteServiceServlet - Why Serializable and how to handle serialVersionUID?

Tags: java, serialization, gwt

Why is `RemoteServiceServlet` Serializable? I can't think of a situation where I want to serialize a Servlet.

If I know that I will never have a need to to so, shall I suppress the warning (`The serializable class does not declare a static final serialVersionUID`)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179743/why-does-httpservlet-implement-serializable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with GWT. The base class for all servlets (javax.servlet.GenericServlet) is already marked as serializable. The reason for this is that a servlet engine may decide to persist the instance state of a servlet class. I am not sure if any container actually implements the functionality, but it is allowed according to the J2EE specification.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice article on the serialVersionUID on http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-06/02-qa-0627-mythser.html

The servlet needs to be serializable because when in a distributed environment, it can be serialized and deserialized by the container.