# Does my Servlet have to implement Serializable?

Tags: java, servlets, serialization

I have a simple Servlet.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
...
}
```

Do I need to `implement Serializable` as well?

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet implements Serializable
{
...
}
```

`HttpServlet` already `implements Serializable`. So, is it redundancy here?

What are the impacts if its implemented and if its not implemented?

Comment: Same reason as to why you make your bean implement Serializable..

Comment: A downvote is unnecessary since user2488578 clearly thought about it. He or she just doesn't have the experience to know why beans are different from servlets and how inheritance works. It isn't wrong to be a beginner.

Comment: @Rupesh I wish to downvote your comments here. Or haven't you been a beginner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HttpServlet already implements Serializable, so even if you don't implement Serializable in your servlet, it still implements Serializable

More information on Serializable and why HttpServlet implements Serializable

> [What does Serializable mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429921/what-does-serializable-mean)
>
> [Why does HttpServlet implement Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179743/why-does-httpservlet-implement-serializable)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to do it. As you say, it is redundant because `HttpServlet` already implements `Serializable`.

Just don't forget to define the `static final long serialVersionUID` field in your `MyServlet` class.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you extend a class, you extend everything about it. So since `HttpServlet` implements `Serializable`, `Serializable` comes along for the ride when you extend `HttpServlet`. No need to do it again yourself.

Answer (score 0):

See this : http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45 I hope it's useful for you

Answer (score 0):

`Serializable` is a `marker interface`. it does `not have any method of it's own`. it is just a `hint` to jvm that the object of child classes would be serializable or writable to streams like file or network.

if a class already implement it, no need to do that again.